# How can i send a string from python to kv fille using Builder.load

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can i use my self.username in my kv file as the title of my MDToolbar.
here is the python code

```
   class GipApp(MDApp):
def build(self,username):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
    self.username = "unknown"
    self.usernameKV = "unknown"
    return screen


def verify(self, username, password):
    if username != "" and password != "":
        for row in MySqlNames:
            if row[0].strip() == username:
                sql = "SELECT Password from ID191774_6itn1project7.Users where Username = %s "
                mycursor.execute(sql, (username))
                TestPassword = mycursor.fetchall()
                for row3 in TestPassword:
                    if row3[0].strip() == password:
                        dialog = MDDialog(title="Login successful")
                        dialog.open()
                        self.username = username
                        GipApp.get_running_app().root.current = 'main'
```

i want to use the new value in self.username as a title in the next kivy code.

```
<MainScreen>:
canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'mountains.jpg'
name: 'main'
NavigationLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        Screen:    
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDToolbar:
                title: ?????????
                left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                elevation :12
                pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .95}
```

i hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is snippets are formatted weirdly I am not sure, but I would suggest setting username to a String property, like so

`import kivy.properties as kypros`

`username = kypros.StringProperty()`

and I wouldn't declare it in the "build" function, I'd rather do it in the GipApp class, (I am assuming that verify and build are methods in this class), and then when setting it in a .kv file, do this: `title: root.username`. I hope that helps, I am not 100% sure because the snippets are horribly formatted. Cheers!